# Can't compile against asm-generic/cmpxchg-local.h

Tags: compiler-construction, linker

Question: what do i need to link to get /asm-generic/cmpxchg-local.h accessible?

---

Info:

I know I'm missing a link some where, but I can't figure out the right command. I'm not very good when it comes to linking for compilers. I tried to compile a simple program to test my access to cmpxchg-local.h. i saw some one do it as "asm-generic/cmpxchg-local.h" but that didn't work either. I ran locate and it found the file here:

```
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.0.0-14/include/asm-generic/cmpxchg-local.h
```

So i tried putting the whole file path into my include like so:

```
#include </usr/src/linux-headers-3.0.0-14/include/asm-generic/cmpxchg-local.h>
#include <stdio>

int main()
{
    printf("Hello world!\n");
}
```

That then proceeded to tell me that it couldn't find linux/irqflags.h. Obviously some linking some where is missing, any advise?

Compiling with:

```
 gcc cmpandswp.c -o test -lm
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't want to include kernel headers in a user program... but what you're looking for is the following GCC flag (from the man pages):

```
   -I dir
       Add the directory dir to the list of directories to be searched for header files.  Directories named by -I are searched before the standard system include directories.  If the
       directory dir is a standard system include directory, the option is ignored to ensure that the default search order for system directories and the special treatment of system
       headers are not defeated .  If dir begins with "=", then the "=" will be replaced by the sysroot prefix; see --sysroot and -isysroot.
```

This way, you can do something like `gcc -I/usr/src/linux-headers-3.0.0-14/include <objects>` and change your include to `#include <asm-generic/cmpxchg-local.h>`.  You'll probably need to add more `-I` paths to compile with that header file (but again, this is probably not what you want to do).